# Handling and aggregating multiple json's with a key in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I have a continuous stream of json's coming through kafka and i am trying to join the same using `apache flink` with a key. 5 of them having same key so i thought to use global window and provide trigger as 5. But the problem is what if only four json's arrived and the fifth one never came. How can I handle such scenarios ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache Flink: Count window with timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783676/apache-flink-count-window-with-timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when doing a join, you always need to provide some definition of the "window" for where joining occurs - see [Window Join](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/operators/joining.html#window-join) documentation. For pure time-based joins, typically you use either a tumbling or a sliding window. This assumes (typical case for data from Kafka) that you have timestamps assigned to every record, which can then be used to determine which events are in the same time window.