# Flink combination of windowByTime and triggerByCount

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-cep, flink-sql, flink-batch

```
source.keyBy(0)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(5)))
    .trigger(PurgingTrigger.of(CountTrigger.of[TimeWindow](2)))
    .process(new TestFun())
```

Explanation:

Let's say I have 3 events[E1, E2, E3], which should be trigger by count, and also it should trigger by time.
I'm using countTrigger to trigger only 2 events(E1 & E2) but the remaining E3 event is not triggering.

**Expected: E3 Event should trigger after the 5 seconds but actually it's triggering only E1 and E2 events**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CountTrigger` you have supplied is replacing the `EventTimeTrigger` that would normally be used with a `TumblingEventTimeWindow`, rather than somehow extending or augmenting it. To get the behavior you want, you'll have to implement a custom trigger that can FIRE a window based on both counting and timing out.

A [google search](https://google.com/search?q=flink+count+trigger+with+timeout&oq=flink+count+trigger+with+timeout) will find some examples and discussion.

Comment: Thanks - This helped me out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49783676/apache-flink-count-window-with-timeout