# Flink custom trigger not triggering onProcessingTime

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a custom trigger currently implemented that is supposed to trigger when there has been `maxElements` processed or `timeoutMs` has elapsed. Currently, the maxElements portion of the trigger works fine and triggers as expected, however the timeout has never been triggered.

In the Flink main job, I have also tried `env.setStreamTimeCharacteristic(TimeCharacteristic.ProcessingTime);`, however this has not been helpful.

Can someone guide me in the right direction? I am lost and unsure where to proceed. Here is my implementation:

```java
public class ElementCountOrTimeoutTrigger<W extends Window> extends Trigger<Object, W> {

    private final long maxElements;
    private final long timeoutMs;
    private long elementCount = 0;
    private long lastTimestamp = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    public ElementCountOrTimeoutTrigger(long maxElements, long timeoutMs) {
        this.maxElements = maxElements;
        this.timeoutMs = timeoutMs;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(Object element, long timestamp, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        elementCount++;
        lastTimestamp = timestamp;
        if (elementCount >= maxElements) {
            elementCount = 0;
            return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("On processing time called");
        System.out.println("Time: " + time);
        System.out.println("Last timestamp: " + lastTimestamp);
        System.out.println("Timeout: " + timeoutMs);
        if (time >= lastTimestamp + timeoutMs) {
            elementCount = 0;
            return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        elementCount = 0;
        lastTimestamp = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    }

    public static <W extends Window> ElementCountOrTimeoutTrigger<W> of(long maxElements, long timeoutMs) {
        return new ElementCountOrTimeoutTrigger<>(maxElements, timeoutMs);
    }
}
```

Edit:

Incorporated a timer, however it is not respecting the delete timer calls:

```java
public class ElementCountOrTimeTrigger<W extends Window> extends Trigger<Object, W> {

    private final long maxElements;
    private final long timeoutMs;
    private int elementCount = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    private long lastTimestamp = Long.MIN_VALUE;
    private long lastTimerExpire = Long.MIN_VALUE;

    public ElementCountOrTimeTrigger(long maxElements, long timeoutMs) {
        this.maxElements = maxElements;
        this.timeoutMs = timeoutMs;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onElement(Object element, long timestamp, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        elementCount++;
        lastTimestamp = ctx.getCurrentProcessingTime();
        if (lastTimerExpire > lastTimestamp) {
            ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(lastTimerExpire);
            System.out.println("Removed the timer due to new element for time: " + lastTimerExpire);
        }
        lastTimerExpire = lastTimestamp + timeoutMs;
        ctx.registerProcessingTimeTimer(lastTimerExpire);
        System.out.println("Registered timer until " + lastTimerExpire);
        if (elementCount >= maxElements) {
            elementCount = 0;
            return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
        }
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onProcessingTime(long time, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Processing time called for time: " + time + " and last timer expire: " + lastTimerExpire);
        System.out.println("Firing and purging");
        elementCount = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        return TriggerResult.FIRE_AND_PURGE;
    }

    @Override
    public TriggerResult onEventTime(long time, W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        return TriggerResult.CONTINUE;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear(W window, TriggerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        elementCount = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
        ctx.deleteProcessingTimeTimer(lastTimerExpire);
    }

    public static <W extends Window> ElementCountOrTimeTrigger<W> of(long maxElements, long timeoutMs) {
        return new ElementCountOrTimeTrigger<>(maxElements, timeoutMs);
    }
}
```

The log it produces:

```
Registered timer until 1683405995456
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683405995456
Registered timer until 1683405997053
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683405997053
Registered timer until 1683405999054
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683405999054
Registered timer until 1683406001054
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683406001054
Registered timer until 1683406003054
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683406003054
Registered timer until 1683406005055
Processing time called for time: 1683405995456 and last timer expire: 1683406005055
Firing and purging
Processing time called for time: 1683405997053 and last timer expire: 1683406005055
Firing and purging
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683406005055
Registered timer until 1683406007055
Removed the timer due to new element for time: 1683406007055
Registered timer until 1683406009055
Processing time called for time: 1683405999054 and last timer expire: 1683406009055
Firing and purging
Processing time called for time: 1683406001054 and last timer expire: 1683406009055
Firing and purging
Processing time called for time: 1683406003054 and last timer expire: 1683406009055
Firing and purging
Processing time called for time: 1683406005055 and last timer expire: 1683406009055
Firing and purging
Processing time called for time: 1683406007055 and last timer expire: 1683406009055
Firing and purging
Processing time called for time: 1683406009055 and last timer expire: 1683406009055
Firing and purging
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't registered a processing time timer, so `onProcessingTime` will never be called.

You can model the timeout part of your custom trigger on the built-in `ProcessingTimeTrigger`, which you'll find here: https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/windowing/triggers/ProcessingTimeTrigger.java

See also this answer, which provides a complete example of something very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49895802/2000823

Comment: Hi David, thanks for helping, I added some timer code and now it will trigger, however a new problem arises as even when I remove the old timers it still gets triggered after I remove them.